# Android webview loadurl to be done in different class and cached

Tags: android, url, webview

My Android app has an Update class and I have, in the same app, another class which opens a website through the webview. The problem is that I would like to have the Update-class to load the url but not showing it, then caching it (if possible, so if the user is offline it should be able to view some of the contents) and then I would be able to show it later on in the app but without the 3 - 10 second loading time.

It's a facebook page and I am in the cold on this one. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I am unable to understand why would you cache the page and show some content to user and after some time you want whole page to be loaded? Can you explain please?

Comment: I want to do this because I have a sequence in my app where I want to load things, there I also want to load the website but not show it. So later on, when the user wants to see it, its no delay. Have a jolly good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. Then Use a background thread to do this when you are in previous activity. Or one solution may be that you load the Url in next activity, as first time it will take time to load but next time it will be cached. Set few properties of the web view as:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

and

```
webView.clearCache(false);
```

Hope this help your cause.